# Adding a simple value to a string

Tags: python, string

If I have a string lets say ohh

```
path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio'
```

And I want to add a `"` at the end of the string how do I do that? Right now I have it like this.

```
path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio'
w = '"'
final = os.path.join(path2, w)
print final
```

However when it prints it out, this is what is returned:

"C:\Users\bgbesase\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio\"

I don't need the `\` I only want the `"`

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The slash you're getting is being added by `os.path.join()`. Instead just treat the string like a string and append like you normally would.

Comment: Use a raw string to avoid the need to escape all the backslashes. `r'"C:\Users\bgbesase\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about?

```
path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio' + '"'
```

Or, as you had it

```
final = path2 + w
```

It's also worth mentioning that you can use raw strings (r'stuff') to avoid having to escape backslashes. Ex.

```
path2 = r'"C:\Users\bgbesase\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio'
```

Answer (score 7):

just do:

```
path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio' + '"'
```

Comment: +1. But it might be worth showing this in the exact same structure the OP had: `final = path2 + w`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `path2+w` is the simplest answer here but you can also use string formatting to make it more readable:

```
>>> path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio' 
>>> '{}"'.format(path2)
'"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio"'
```

If `path2` was long than it's much easier to use string formatting than adding a `+` at the end of the string.

```
>>> path2 = '"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio'
>>> w = '"'
>>> "{}{}".format(path2,w)
'"C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual Studio"'
```

Comment: If you're going to give a fun answer, have more fun with it. What about `''.join(itertools.chain(path2, w))`? But I'm sure you can come up with something even better.

Answer (score 0):

From Python documentation [Common pathname manipulations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) section:

> The return value is the concatenation of path1, and optionally path2,
>   etc., with exactly one directory separator (os.sep) following each
>   non-empty part except the last.

In this case, `os.path.join()` treats your string '"' as path part and adds the separator. Since you are not joining two parts of path you need to use string concatenation or [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).
The simplest would be just to add two strings:

```
final = path2 + '"'
```

You can actually modify path2 using `+=` operator:

```
path2 += '"'
```